# Proof of the Discriminant Law of Conics

Tags: conic-sections

Does anyone know a good resource and or know the proof for the Discriminant Law of Conics ($B^2 - 4AC > 0$ , Hyperbola ....)

Thanks

Comment: To me, the most clear demonstration is given by using *homogeneous coordinates* , and thereby looking for the *intersections at infinity* .

Comment: Perhaps, a full statement of the theorem might help identify it. Did you mean [this](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Conic_section#Discriminant)?